# Insert " < " into html file using php

Tags: php, html

Is there a way I can insert `<` or `>` in HTML file using PHP. Here is a a part of code

```
<?php
$custom_tag = $searchNode->nodeValue = "<";
$custom_tag = $searchNode->setAttribute("data-mark", $theme_name);
$custom_tag = $dom->saveHTML($searchNode);
$root = $searchNode->parentNode;
$root->removeChild($searchNode);
$test = $dom->createTextNode("<?php echo '$custom_tag'; ?>");

$root->appendChild($test);
$saved_file_in_HTML = $dom->saveHTML();
$saved_file = htmlspecialchars_decode($saved_file_in_HTML);
file_put_contents("test.html", $saved_file);
```

The problem is that I get `&lt;` using above method and I would like to have `<`.

**EDIT:**
Full code:

```
    if($searchNode->hasAttribute('data-put_page_content')) {
    $custom_tag = $searchNode->nodeValue = "'; \$up_level = null; \$path_to_file = 'DATABASE/PAGES/' . basename(\$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '.php') . '.txt'; for(\$x = 0; \$x < 1; ) { if(is_file(\$up_level.\$path_to_file)) { \$x = 1; include(\$up_level.\$path_to_file); } else if(!is_file(\$up_level.\$path_to_file)) { \$up_level .= '../'; } }; echo '";
    $custom_tag = $searchNode->setAttribute("data-mark", $theme_name);
    $custom_tag = $dom->saveHTML($searchNode);
    $root = $searchNode->parentNode;
    $root->removeChild($searchNode);
    $test = $dom->createTextNode("<?php echo '$custom_tag'; ?>");

    $root->appendChild($test);
    $saved_file_in_HTML = $dom->saveHTML();
    $saved_file = htmlspecialchars_decode($saved_file_in_HTML);
    file_put_contents("../THEMES/ACTIVE/". $theme_name ."/" . $trimed_file, $saved_file);
    copy("../THEMES/ACTIVE/" . $theme_name . "/structure/index.php", "../THEMES/ACTIVE/" . $theme_name ."/index.php");
    header("Location: editor.php");         

}
```

**FINAL EDIT:**
If you want to have `>` or `<` using PHP DOMs methods, it is working using `createTextNode()` method.

Comment: `html_entity_decode`.. use this php built in function...

Comment: `$test = $dom->createTextNode("<?php echo html_entity_decode($custom_tag); ?>");`

Comment: It is not working. Maybe function has to work it self before inserting into html file?

Comment: Are you trying to pre-generate templates?

Comment: Something like that. I am creating my own small CMS.

Comment: Let it be on record that I think generating templates with PHP code in them is generally a bad idea. Now, carry on…

Comment: And let me put it on record that while writing your own CMS is a great learning exercise, if you plan to create real web sites, you are strongly advised to download an existing CMS package with a proven security record.

Comment: @Spudley security is the second part of learning. I am creating flat file CMS so password is saved in text file protected with .htaccess... for now.

Comment: Rather than editing your question to include an answer, you should answer your own question and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The original question appears to concern how to use PHP to manufacture an HTML tag, so I'll address that question.  While it is a good idea to use htmlentities(), you also need to be aware that it's primary purpose is to protect your code so that a malicious user doesn't inject it with javascript or other tags that could create security problems.  In this case, the only way to generate HTML is to create HTML and PHP provides at least three ways to accomplish this feat.

You may write code such as the following:

```
<?php

define("LF_AB","<");
define("RT_AB",">");
echo LF_AB,"div",RT_AB,"\n";
echo "content\n";
echo LF_AB,"/div",RT_AB,"\n";
```

The code produces start and end div tags with some minimal content. Note, the defines are optional, i.e. one could code in a more straightforward fashion `<?php echo "<"; ?>` instead of resorting to using a define() to generate the left-angle tag character.

However, if one is wary of generating HTML in this manner, then you may also use html_entity_decode:

```
<?php
define("LF_AB",html_entity_decode("<"));
define("RT_AB",html_entity_decode(">"));
echo LF_AB,"div",RT_AB,"\n";
echo "content\n";
echo LF_AB,"/div",RT_AB,"\n";
```

This example treats the arguments to html_entity_decode as harmless HTML entities and then converts them into HTML left and right angle characters respectively.

Alternately, you could also take advantage of the DOM with PHP, even with an existing HTML page, as follows:

```
<?php
function displayContent()
{
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $element = $dom->createElement('div', 'My great content');
    $dom->appendChild($element);
    echo $dom->saveHTML();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled</title>
<style>
div {
  background:#ccbbcc;
  color:#009;
  font-weight:bold;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php displayContent(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Note: the Dom method createTextNode true to its name creates text and not HTML, i.e. the browser will only interpret the right and left angle characters as text without any additional meaning.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, I think you could use < and > in the first place. They should be rendered as HTML. Might save you some coding. Let me know if it works.